# Position in x,y of the endpoint of a circle/arc

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw lines in a circle like the spokes of a wheel. I am getting stuck because I do not know how to get the coordinates from the end point of the circle. It all works well as long as I draw lines from the rim to the centre of the circle but I am unable to make the lines stop on the inner circle, the hub of the wheel.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.arc(75, 75, 70, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.arc(75, 75, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        var part = ( 2 * Math.PI ) / 8;
        for( i=1; i<=8; i++ ) {
            ctx.arc(75, 75, 70, 0, (part*i) );
            ctx.lineTo( 75, 75 );
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result of the above script:
[image]

Maybe the solution is simple, but I have only discovered the canvas object in javascript yesterday.
Is there a way to convert the position where the arc ends, to its x and y coordinates?
I know I can calculate these positions using math but I was hoping for an easier solution.

Comment: `ctx.lineTo( 75, 75 );` - that's the endpoint of those lines, in the middle of your circle. So for each line, you would have to calculate the position where it crosses the inner circle, and then supply _that_ as the endpoint instead.

Comment: No it gets more complicated when spokes cross in the wheel. The end point is never really in the centre point but always on the inner circle

Comment: And that's why I just said, that you need to calculate the coordinates of that point, and then use those coordinates instead of the fixed `75, 75` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution involves a little bit of trigonometry and math.

Consider the following code. I replaced the numbers with variables with intuitive names.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

const centerX = 75;
const centerY = 75;
const outerRadius = 70;
const innerRadius = 20;

ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, innerRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, outerRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
var part = (2 * Math.PI) / 8;
for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  const angle = i * part;
  ctx.moveTo(centerX + innerRadius * Math.cos(angle), centerY + innerRadius * Math.sin(angle));
  ctx.lineTo(centerX + outerRadius * Math.cos(angle), centerY + outerRadius * Math.sin(angle));
}
ctx.stroke();
```

Basically, you need to translate the endpoints of the line by a certain amount. This amount will depend on the radius, but changes with the rotation angle. This where `sin` and `cos` come in.

```
newX = oldX + radius * cos(angle)
newY = oldY + radius * sin(angle)
```

`radius * sin(a)` and `radius * cos(a)` will give the projection of the rotated distance on the x and y axis

`radius` is taken as the radius of inner and outer rims. `oldX` and `oldY` are just the centers of these rims.

This gives the following result.

[image: result]

Comment: I just edited your answer to include a runnable [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex), in doing so I took the liberty of moving the JavaScript out of the HTML that OP originally posted. If you'd rather that the HTML be there, please do [edit] the answer to reinsert it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the math. I was hoping I could do without it. Not that I am afraid of coding but because it is redundant. The end of the circle was already calculated by the "arc" function in the background. If only .arc could return a Point to return the end of the line, or the start point if the counterclockwise argument is supplied.
With the "lineTo" or "arcTo" functions we know the endpoint because we supplied them ourselves but in case of "arc", it is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution with almost no maths, you could just draw two circles. Then draw a spoke, [`rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate) ⅛ turn, add another spoke, and repeat until all the spokes are in.

I don't like working with π, so this answer uses [turns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(angle)) instead. 1 turn is 1 one full circle, aka 360° or 2π radians.

```js
const TURN = 2 * Math.PI;

const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(75, 75); // change the origin to (75,75)
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

const radiusA = 20;
const radiusB = 70;
const spokeCount = 8;

// arc centre should be (0,0) since we moved the origin to (75,75)
ctx.arc(0, 0, radiusA, 0, 1*TURN);
ctx.moveTo(radiusB, 0); // [optional] prevents line between the two circles
ctx.arc(0, 0, radiusB, 0, 1*TURN);
for (let i = 0; i < spokeCount; ++i) {
  // rotate around the origin
  ctx.rotate(1*TURN / spokeCount);
  ctx.moveTo(radiusA, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(radiusB, 0);
}
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas>wheel</canvas>
```

Note that if this is not the only thing you're drawing, you might want to move the origin back.

```
ctx.translate(-75, -75)
```